# Array in struct

Tags: c

I want an array in a struct but I am unsure how to do it. I can only use one array in the struct.

```
typedef struct 
{
    int arr[10];
} coords;


coords x;

printf("Enter X coordinates: ");

scanf("%d", x.arr[0]);
scanf("%d", x.arr[1]);
scanf("%d", x.arr[2]);
...
```

My problem is how do I also enter the X values in the array? I was first thinking of a two dimensional array `arr[10][10]` but it wouldn't work because I have some calculations to do on the X values.

Is the proper way just do define a new object like `coords x;` and just do it all over?

**Basically I want the struct to contain one (1) array. I want the struct to contain x and y coordinates for a map, which the user inputs. Later in the program I want to do calculations with ONLY the x values**.

Comment: I don't understand (almost) anything. Can you rephrase?

Comment: I updated the OP, maybe something got clearer. :)

Comment: Can you give us an example of the data you want to use?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a couple of arrays in one struct in a following way:

```js
typedef struct 
{
    int x[10];
    int y[10];
} coords;


coords c;

printf("Enter a couple of X coordinates: ");
scanf("%d", &c.x[0]);
scanf("%d", &c.x[1]);

printf("Enter a couple of Y coordinates: ");
scanf("%d", &c.y[0]);
scanf("%d", &c.y[1]);
```

Note that in `scanf()` you should pass pointers to array elements and not elements.

Also you can do it using **one** 2-D array (X_COOR and Y_COOR can be removed):

```js
#define X_COOR 0
#define Y_COOR 1
typedef struct 
{
    int coords[2][10];
} coords;    

coords c;

printf("Enter a couple of X coordinates: ");
scanf("%d", &c.coords[X_COOR][0]);
scanf("%d", &c.coords[X_COOR][1]);

printf("Enter a couple of Y coordinates: ");
scanf("%d", &c.coords[Y_COOR][0]);
scanf("%d", &c.coords[Y_COOR][1]);
```

Comment: But I can only have one array in the struct, not several.

Comment: @user3005287 Then how do you want to store them in one array? Interleaved? Mean x,y,x,y...

Comment: @user3005287 One 2-d array is in the answer.

Comment: @user3005287 if Michael's answer here doesn't answers your question yet, then I believe you'll have to rephrase it **again**

Answer (score 1):

A nicer solution is of course to do an array of struct, since the core thing you're interested in (a coordinate expressed as a pair of values) can be modelled well as a struct:

```
typedef struct {
  int x, y;
} coordinate;
```

then you can declare an array easily enough:

```
coordinate my_coords[100];
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is fine except you have to place `&` operator before the argument of each `scanf`.

```
scanf("%d", &x.arr[0]);
```

For Y co-ordinates you should have to define another array inside your structure.

Answer (score 0):

Create another struct for array element:

```
typedef struct 
{
    int x;
    int y;
} coord;

typedef struct 
{
    coord arr[10];
} coords;
```

Usage:

```
scanf("%d", &x.arr[0].x);
```